# Is there a way to subscribe to the content of Delicious bookmarks as an RSS feed?

Tags: rss, delicious, bookmarks

The idea is to get the full/partial summary of bookmarks received as Delicious RSS feeds and not just links.

For example if I subscribe to http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/test, I only receive bookmarks as feeds - not the actual feed entry pointed by the bookmark.

Is it possible to get the content, not the URL?

Comment: What do you mean by "actual feed entry pointed by the bookmark"? Do you mean the page content?

Comment: @tic Yes.. the content not the URL or link.

Answer (score 3):

The intended purpose of [RSS](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification/) is to distribute links and related metadata and not to actually distribute content.

Now, that said, there is a field named `description` that allows for text to be stored.  Normally, this is going to be a short description or summary of the content but not the actual content.  A good example is [Slashdot](http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot), which displays a summary and relevant links.  A different take on the description field is to include the first sentence/paragraph of content, as used by [Penny Arcade](http://delicious.com/).  And, finally, there are others that actually do distribute content through feeds, such as [Ars Technica](http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/science/).

With [Delicious](http://delicious.com/), the description field is actually something that you specify when creating the bookmark.  See the highlighted portion in the screenshot.  So, if you have some way of capturing content when the bookmark is created, then you see the content in the feed.  Of course, even if you do this, then the content may not necessarily be in sync with the original source.

[image: Entering an RSS description in Delicious]